# Total brightness from emission spectra?

Tags: experimental-physics, astronomy, spectroscopy, photometry

Some background: I'm looking to analyze stars through a telescope; I'd like get both the visual spectrum and the brightness of each target. I'd also like to have to build/carry as few instruments as I can get away with.

If I were to take a full visual emission spectrum of the target - plotting absolute intensities for each wavelength, rather than relative - and then, with the same instrument, take a spectrum of a reference star, it seems logical to me that I could integrate under both graphs and compare the two to get a measure of total relative (visual) brightness. Am I right?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Astronomy.SE];  if you don't get satisfactory answers here, I would try over there.

Comment: There are a lot of different measures of 'brightness' in astronomy/physics, including [luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity), 'apparent brightness' (seems much closer to [Luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance), or human-perceived brightness), '[apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude)' (which takes the star's distance into account), and more.  Can you confirm that Luminance is the definition of 'brightness' you are asking about? So far it seems the closest, based on your description.